# .net core projects code coverage visual studio 2017

Tags: code-coverage, visual-studio-2017, xunit, vs-unit-testing-framework

I am using Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 to develop my .net core projects.

My solution also has some unit test projects and I want to view my current Code coverage.

When I clicked Test -> Analyze Code Coverage -> All tests. All my unit tests ran but in Code Coverage Results it only reported code coverage for my unit test projects which doesn't make any sense to me.

**Question 1**: Do you guys experience the same issue with me? Any solution for this? I also need to set up build definition in VSTS to report code coverage.

[image]

**Question 2**: Also when I right clicked to debug 1 of my unit test. It executes ALL of my unit tests. Is this a bug in VS2017?

Update1: I found this topic: https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest/issues/597

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Even with the "fixed" version I had issues (Only able to see code coverage for the test projects, not the actual projects I was testing). To workaround the problem I removed the `<DebugType>Full</DebugType>` from the test project.

So, as a summary:

1. Add package Microsoft.CodeCoverage (1.0.3) into your test project.
2. Add the `<DebugType>Full</DebugType>` tag on the .csproj file **on
   the projects we want to see code coverage values** (inside `<PropertyGroup>` as explained on the [vstest github link](https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest-docs/blob/master/docs/analyze.md#coverage)).
3. Run unit tests.
4. On the "Test Explorer" select passed unit tests, right click -> "Analyze Code Coverage for Selected Tests".
5. You should see code coverage for your assemblies.

My setup (Minimal setup?)

- xunit (2.3.1)
- xunit.runner.visualstudio (2.3.1)
- Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk (15.3.0)
- Microsoft.CodeCoverage (1.0.3)
- Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 (15.4.1)

Comment: I have VS2017 Pro (15.5.2), same packages as listed above, however after running the unit tests, have no right-click context menu named "Analyze Code Coverage".

Comment: oh, I looked at the github link you mentioned, and see that it now requires Visual Studio ENTERPRISE.  Thanks a lot Micro$oft.

Comment: I've been waiting for code coverage in .NET Core for so long...  This worked great!  thanks!

Comment: This worked for me. The following are additional steps for NUnit:

Comment: Sorry time limit expired to edit above comment. Additional steps for NUnit:
- Update Unit and Test adaptor to 3.9

- Need to add a reference to Mono.Cecil 0.10.0-beta7

The beta is required for .NET Standard support. Once 0.10.0 is out of beta the NUnit guys will included it in the regular NuGet package.
See https://github.com/nunit/nunit3-vs-adapter/issues/325 . Once it's closed the extra reference shouldn't be required.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks

Comment: lol thanks @Tony ... I even find myself coming back for this sometimes

Answer (score 9):

You can try dotCover from Jetbrains. https://www.jetbrains.com/dotcover/features/

> dotCover is a .NET unit testing and code coverage tool that works right in Visual Studio, helps you know to what extent your code is covered with unit tests, provides great ways to visualize code coverage, and is Continuous Integration ready. dotCover calculates and reports statement-level code coverage in applications targeting .NET Framework, Silverlight, and .NET Core.

It works fine with .NET Core & can show code coverage.

> Supports multiple unit testing frameworks, namely MSTest, NUnit, xUnit (all out of the box) and MSpec (via a plug-in).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Based on this article ([Code Coverage does not work in the IDE with netcoreapp1.x projects (VS 2017 RTM](https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest/issues/597)):

> Code coverage is currently not implemented for netcore projects. The
>   work on this issue is in progress, it will come as part of post RTW
>   releases.

Comment: Any update on this? Come'n they released VS 2017 two months ago and we still can't cover xUnit tests?

Comment: Apparently it works in the 15.3 preview: https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest-docs/blob/master/docs/analyze.md#coverage

Answer (score 1):

It looks like they are still working out the infrastructure (data collectors) bits before releasing. They are supposedly close.

https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest/issues/579

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been fixed with Version 15.3:

https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest-docs/blob/master/docs/analyze.md#coverage

Comment: Thanks. I haven't taken a look at it but looks like it's on its way.

Answer (score 0):

JDC's answer helped me to include my actual projects but I could not get rid of the test projects in the coverage report.
I managed it by adding a "CodeCoverage.runsettings" in my XUnit test project with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- File name extension must be .runsettings -->
<RunSettings>
  <DataCollectionRunSettings>
    <DataCollectors>
      <DataCollector friendlyName="Code Coverage" uri="datacollector://Microsoft/CodeCoverage/2.0" assemblyQualifiedName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.DynamicCoverageDataCollector, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TraceCollector, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a">
        <Configuration>
          <CodeCoverage>
            <ModulePaths>
              <Exclude>
                <ModulePath>.*\.Tests.dll$</ModulePath>
                <!-- Add more ModulePath nodes here. -->
              </Exclude>
            </ModulePaths>
          </CodeCoverage>
        </Configuration>
      </DataCollector>
    </DataCollectors>
  </DataCollectionRunSettings>
</RunSettings>
```

The important part here is to exclude the test project in the ModulePaths section.

Comment: I know this response is pretty late... did you check if you have `<DebugType>Full</DebugType>` (inside `<PropertyGroup>`) in the csproj file of your test projects? if that's the case, remove it and you should get rid of them