# Code coverage in dotnet core 1.1 using visual studio 15.3

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, code-coverage

How do I get code coverage to work in a dot net core 1.1 project?
I get a message saying empty results generated. I currently have code coverage 1.3 installed in a visual studio 15.3 instance.

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual studio 2017 15.3 still not support code coverage.

It's just added live unit support.

You can show code coverage with third party only

[.net core projects code coverage visual studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43011072/net-core-projects-code-coverage-visual-studio-2017/45185946#45185946)